# im working to add to my bot some minigames ,!coinflip or !rps

Tags: node.js, discord.js

this is the code that i started with

` const discord = require('discord.js');
const client = new discord.Client;

client.on('ready', () => {  `

and there i think should be my !rps or !coinflip

Comment: so what is your question?

Comment: i just want to know how i could add a !coinflip command or !rps , if exist or is possible

Comment: Well firstly do you know how to handle commands? How to work with discord.js at all? A coin flip is pretty simple so I'm assuming not, which is fine, but you should look up a tutorial on getting started with discord.js first.

Comment: ok man , so it s possible , do u have any special vid tutorial or i just search on youtube ?anyway thx ;3

Comment: You don't wanna just find a tutorial and copy it. I suggest you try learning the language. Here are some resources:
CodeCademy online course: https://www.codecademy.com/learn/javascript
Eloquent Javascript, free book: http://eloquentjavascript.net/
MDN's JavaScript guide: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Introduction
You Don't Know JS (free book series): https://github.com/getify/You-Dont-Know-JS
Some Node: https://nodeschool.io/ 
Javascript reference/docs: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference

Good luck!

Comment: The YouTube channel [TheCodeSource](https://www.youtube.com/channel/UCNXt2MrZaqfIBknamqwzeXA) has some really good tutorials for discord.js, beginning really simple and going to pretty ascended. If I was you I would take a look at that channel.